# JSTree - не возникает событие open_node

Tags: jquery, jstree

Имеем структуру: пакет-документ-страница.
Имеем API, выдающее данные по запросу:

```
/package - выдаёт список пакетов
/package/id - выдаёт список документов в пакете
/document/id - выдаёт страницы в документе
```

Нужно это дело выдавать в `JSTree` с lazy-load, т.е. детишек подгружать только при разворачивании соответствующего родителя.
Первый уровень загружается по кнопке с фильтрацией по дате вызовом функции `applyFilter`.
Получился такой код:

```
function applyFilter() { 
    var verificationApiAddress = 'http://localhost:50352/Zufir/VerificationAPI/1.0.0';

    var params = {
        importStartDate: importDateBegin,
        importEndDate: importDateEnd,
    };

    $.ajax({

        url: verificationApiAddress + '/package',
        method: 'get',
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        data: params
    })
        .success(function (data) {
            $("#packagesTree").jstree({
                "plugins": ["themes", "types"],
                "core": {
                    "themes": { name: "proton" },
                    "types": {
                        "package": {
                            "max_children": -1,
                            "max_depth": -1,
                            "valid_children": "all"
                        },
                        "document": {
                            "max_children": -1,
                            "max_depth": -1,
                            "valid_children": "all"
                        },
                        "page": {
                            "max_children": -1,
                            "max_depth": -1,
                            "valid_children": "all"
                        }
                    },
                    "data": (function () {
                        var result = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            result.push({
                                id: data[i].id,
                                text: data[i].name,
                                children: true,
                                type: "package"
                            });
                        }
                        return result;
                    })()
                }
            }).on("open_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                console.log('open!');
                var node = data.node;
                var childType = "";
                var url = "";
                if (!node.children.length > 0) {
                    if (node.type == "package") {
                        url = "/package/" + node.id;
                        childType = "document";
                    }

                    if (node.type == "document") {
                        url = "/document/" + node.id;
                        childType = "page";
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: verificationApiAddress + url,
                        method: 'get',
                        crossDomain: true,
                        cache: false,
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: false
                        },
                        data: params
                    })
                    .success(function (ajaxResult) {
                        var result = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            result.push({
                                id: data[i].id,
                                text: data[i].name,
                                children: true,
                                type: "package"
                            });
                        }
                        node.children = result;
                    })
                }
            }            
            );
        })
    .error(function (obj, status, err) { console.log("Ошибка получения пакетов: ", err); });


}
```

Увы, мой опыт в общении с JS минимален, так что скорее всего что-то тут не так.
Первый уровень подгружается, но событие на `open_node` не выстреливает.

Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 0):

```
                .success(function (ajaxResult) {
                    var result = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // ajaxResult.length ??
                      ...
```

Comment: Действительно. Копипаст - зло. Но проблема не в этом - я не вижу даже `console.log('open!');`